# Try to learn preformance of hadoop cluster setup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new one for hadoop and I setup Hadoop multi node cluster with two data nodes.But when I am Trying to run mapreduce application with 2GB file, it is geting the more time or it is not working.I want to compare performance of hadoop cluster using these two nodes is it possible then how ?

Comment: When processing a 2GB file, big data is not for you and your overhead might be to large. But do please add more information an what it is exactly that you are doing, what you have set up etc.

Comment: Consider hadoop overhead and choose the right solution. Big data is not just about volume.